# How do I construct params for a get request?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to do:

```
export interface ApiCallOptions {
  abc: string,
  xyz: number
}
makeRequest (options: ApiCallOptions) {
  return this.http.get('/some/path/to/endpoint', { params: options });
}
```

I get an error that ApiCallOptions isn't a HttpParams object...  I tried casting options as HttpParams, still fails..

So then I tried:

```
  const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: options });
  return this.http.get('/some/path/to/endpoint', { params: params });
```

And I get:

> The expected type comes from property 'fromObject' which is declared
> here on type 'HttpParamsOptions'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try: `const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: options } as HttpParamsOptions);`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
makeRequest (options: ApiCallOptions) {
  return this.http.get('/some/path/to/endpoint', { params: this.buildParams(options) });
}

private buildParams(params) {
  let httpParams = new HttpParams();
  let keys = Object.keys(params);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (params[key] !== null) {
      httpParams = httpParams.append(key, params[key]);
    }
  });
  return httpParams;
}
```

What is the outcome?

Comment: is this really the "angular way?"  Seems so ridiculous to have that much code to make a simple get request.

Comment: That is because there are generators like OpenAPI that perform that work for you: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator
The generator take a specification as input, and generates your model/dto and services requests. However, is my solution working?

Answer (score 0):

From [`HttpParamsOptions`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/41e2a68e30c12e5ad3e26047c3a4032e9aa1a6e1/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L128-L140)

```js
export interface HttpParamsOptions {
  /**
   * String representation of the HTTP parameters in URL-query-string format.
   * Mutually exclusive with `fromObject`.
   */
  fromString?: string;

  /** Object map of the HTTP parameters. Mutually exclusive with `fromString`. */
  fromObject?: {[param: string]: string|number|boolean|ReadonlyArray<string|number|boolean>};

  /** Encoding codec used to parse and serialize the parameters. */
  encoder?: HttpParameterCodec;
}
```

For the `fromObject` property, it implements the index signature with property name as string.

---

For the `HttpParams` instance:

```js
import {
  HttpParamsOptions,
} from '@angular/common/http';

const paramsOption = {
  fromObject: options as { [key: string]: any },
} as HttpParamsOptions;
const params = new HttpParams(paramsOption);
```

Comment: But modifying the interface like that seems obnoxious..  The point is to specify WHAT is expected to be passed to the endpoint.  adding `[key: string]: any` totally removes any benefit and again makes me say "UGH TYPESCRIPT IS TERRIBLE!!!"